# Vue Method alway called (not only on-click)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, methods

I'm quite new to vue and still trying to understand the basics behind my code. 
Now I have a problem with a Method. It should only be called when the user clicks on the button. But instead it is always called. I added a alert()/ console.log(), which are then shown multiple times.

here some code:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <center>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th><button  :on-click="click(1)" class="white1"><li v-bind:class="{'icon': containertyp[1] == 'l', 'iconLH': containertyp[1] == 'lh', 'iconBH': containertyp[1] == 'bh'}"></li></button></th>
                    <th><button  :on-click="click(2)" class="white1"><li v-bind:class="{'icon': containertyp[2] == 'l', 'iconLH': containertyp[2] == 'lh', 'iconBS': containertyp[2] == 'bs'}"></li></button></th>
                    <th><button  :on-click="click(3)" class="white1"><li v-bind:class="{'icon': containertyp[3] == 'l', 'iconLH': containertyp[3] == 'lh', 'iconBS': containertyp[3] == 'bs'}"></li></button></th> 
                <tr>    
            </table>
        </center>
    </div>
</template>

export default {
    data: function () {
        return {
            nr: [],
            containertyp: [],
        }
    },
    methods: {
        click(number) {

            for (var i = 0; i < 27; i++) {
                this.nr[i] = false;
                if (number == i) {
                    this.nr[i] = true;
                }
            };
            console.log(this.nr);
            EventBus.$emit('containerclicked');

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This attribute is a strange mixture of different syntaxes:

```
:on-click="click(1)"
```

It's unclear whether you're trying to bind the `onclick` attribute of the element or (more likely) add a Vue click listener to the element.

Most likely what you actually want is this:

```
@click="click(1)"
```

The `@` is shorthand for `v-on:`, whereas the `:` in your original code is short for `v-bind:`. Trying to bind an attribute called `on-click` is perfectly valid but it will be treated as a custom attribute as `on-click` isn't actually a thing. The binding is evaluated during rendering to determine the value of the attribute, which is why you'll see the logging during rendering.

Answer (score 0):

try to pass a event to the click handlers method `click(number, event)` and stop the propagation with `event.preventDefault()`.